Are individual wage negotiations protected under CA law?
Section 923 of the CA labor code declares the public policy of CA:

In the interpretation and application of this chapter, the public policy of this State is declared as follows:
Negotiation of terms and conditions of labor should result from
voluntary agreement between employer and employees. Governmental
authority has permitted and encouraged employers to organize in the
corporate and other forms of capital control. In dealing with such
employers, the individual unorganized worker is helpless to exercise
actual liberty of contract and to protect his freedom of labor, and
thereby to obtain acceptable terms and conditions of employment.
Therefore it is necessary that the individual workman have full
freedom of association, self-organization, and designation of
representatives of his own choosing, to negotiate the terms and
conditions of his employment, and that he shall be free from the
interference, restraint, or coercion of employers of labor, or their
agents, in the designation of such representatives or in
self-organization or in other concerted activities for the purpose of
collective bargaining or other mutual aid or protection.

A wrongful termination claim (“Tameny claim”) lies where the employer violates a fundamental public policy based on a constitutional or statutory provision. See, e.g., Grant-Burton v. Covenant Care, Inc., 99 Cal.App.4th 1361, 122 Cal. Rptr. 2d 204 (Cal. Ct. App. 2002).
If an employee is terminated for engaging in individual (i.e., not collective) wage negotiations, does he have a wrongful termination claim?

See the text you're quoted, I highlighted the relevant part to your original question:

Therefore it is necessary that the individual workman have full freedom of association, self-organization, and designation of representatives of his own choosing, to negotiate the terms and conditions of his employment, and that he shall be free from the interference, restraint, or coercion of employers of labor, or their agents, in the designation of such representatives or in self-organization or in other concerted activities for the purpose of collective bargaining or other mutual aid or protection

The full text also includes the actual instruction:


In the interpretation and application of this chapter, the public policy of this State is declared as follows: ... (follows the text quoted in the question)


This means that this section is a guidance to courts as to how the sections in the chapter are to be interpreted and to agencies as to how they're to be applied.

However, your updated question focuses on whether an employee is protected just because they're attempting to negotiate the terms of their employment. The answer to that is generally no.
The chapter in question (California Labor Code Div 2 Part 3 Chapter 1) is mostly focused on attempts to influence employees and prospective employees with regards to labor unions, and the choice of law and venue for conflict resolution. Given in your comments you seem to imply there's a specific scenario that you're interested in, the context of this section matters. The content of the negotiations is not covered beyond the restrictions on applicable law and venue, only the manner (through representatives, as collective, etc).

Is terminating an employee for engaging in individual (i.e., not collective) wage negotiations a violation of public policy?

This question is not relevant to the section you quoted. Terminating due to disagreement on terms is not the same as terminating due to the employee's insisting on delegating representatives to the negotiations.
California is generally an at-will employment State and neither employees are required to work against their will, nor the employers are required to employ against their will. Anti-discrimination laws apply to reasoning, and wage negotiations may or may not be protected activity (it's not), but not under the section you quoted.

A wrongful termination claim (“Tameny claim”) lies where the employer violates a fundamental public policy based on a constitutional or statutory provision. See, e.g., Grant-Burton v. Covenant Care, Inc., 99 Cal.App.4th 1361, 122 Cal. Rptr. 2d 204 (Cal. Ct. App. 2002).
So the question (poorly worded, I concede) is whether firing an employee for engaging in individual wage negotiations is a violation of public policy.
Section 923 declares the public policy of CA.

Updated the question. The question is whether employees have a right to negotiate the terms of their employment individually. The NLRA, for example, protects collective negotiation but not individual negotiation.

Would appreciate downvoters to comment

@JoshJohnson They can't require you to join a union in order to negotiate, that's what this section is about. If there's a law saying that they have to negiotiate with individuals, that would be a different section.

You're missing the introduction to that section:

In the interpretation and application of this chapter, the
public policy of this State is declared as follows:

So this section doesn't specify the actual law, it's just the rationale for the other sections of the chapter. The sections it refers to are about the right of employees to choose whether to join labor unions -- they can't be coerced to or prohibited from joining unions. I don't think it's about the types of negotiation available to union and non-union employees.

This section does in fact specify the actual law.
